# Android - Convert Image to Bytes in C# and Convert them to Image in Android

Tags: c#, android, web-services, bitmap, byte

I'm using the C# to convert Images into Bytes or other formats(like Base64) and I'll store     them to SQL Server database.Using web service(REST) I would like to get that encoded data and to    display as an Image in **Android**. My Major doubt is that the Bytes or Base64 in the C# same as in the Android ?. Anybody,please give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

They both should work cross language since they're just a serializable representation of the file contents, no real language specific stuff.

For the bytes, you can use the [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) to get an image in android, and to convert a base64 encoded image to a bitmap, you can use this to get a byte-array and the use the `BitmapFactory`

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```